# Changing wsdl:part name

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

Is there any way of changing the `name` of a message part in the WSDL? I have this on my WSDL:

```
<wsdl:message name="getDataRequestMsg">
    <wsdl:part name="getData" element="tns:getData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDataRequestMsg_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="Header" element="tns:Header"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDataResponseMsg">
    <wsdl:part name="getDataResponse" element="tns:getDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDataResponseMsg_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="Header" element="tns:Header"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

I'm using a `MessageContractAttribute` and I can actually change the name using the respetive `name` attribute on the `MessageBodyMemberAttribute`, but it also changes the `element` name and that's not what I intended. My MessageContract is as follows:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class getDataRequestMsg
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute()]
    public Header[] Header;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute()]
    public getData getData;

    public getDataRequestMsg()
    {
    }

    public getDataRequestMsg(Header[] Header, getData getData)
    {
        this.Header = Header;
        this.getData = getData;
    }
}

[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class getDataResponseMsg
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute()]
    public Header[] Header;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute()]
    public getDataResponse getDataResponse;

    public getDataResponseMsg()
    {
    }

    public getDataResponseMsg(Header[] Header, getDataResponse getDataResponse)
    {
        this.Header = Header;
        this.getDataResponse = getDataResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebMethod()]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("your_element_name")]
public your_type YourMethod()
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some explanation would greatly improve the quality of the answer and help other users who may encounter similar problems in the future
Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: even though the answer is not structured properly, it does indeed address and resolve the issue. the key is this line:

[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("your_element_name")]

I was trying with System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute with no luck.